# Solid state diffusion as a function of shear stress

Tags: stress-strain, diffusion

I am hoping to get some clarification on the impact of shear stress or shear strain on atomic diffusion in a metallic solid. More specifically, will the kinetics for the dissolution of secondary phase particles/precipitates be greater under the influence of a plastic shear stress.

I have read a paper by Cowern on diffusion in strained Si (Ge), which suggested that diffusion is faster under the influence of a compressive strain (and slower under a tensile strain), but am not unequivocally sure on how this translates to a shear stress/strain.